# Rails calculate time difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried such code, but it doesn't work:

```
require 'time_diff'

cur_time = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
time_diff_components = Time.diff(@art.datetime_of_update, Time.parse(cur_time))
if  @art.PRICEM.to_f >= eprice.to_f || @art.PRICEM.blank? && time_diff_components[:hour] < 3 &&
```

but timediff is 0, in db time looks like this:

> 2012-08-28 19:53:12

How calculate difference in hour's between now and db?

Comment: If you just want the time in hours, then `time_diff` is not the library you want to use. Just subtract the two times from each other and divide by `1.hour`

Comment: To be clear, if the difference between 2 times is "1 day and 2 hours" then `time_diff_components[:hour]` will be 2 (not 26). That doesn't sound like what you want?

Comment: yes, but see solve of Jon Skeet

Comment: Sure, and he gave you a solution that didn't use `Time.diff` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you should look at these two lines:

```
cur_time = Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
time_diff_components = Time.diff(@art.datetime_of_update, Time.parse(cur_time))
```

Why would you *format* the time and then only use the value as the input to a parsing operation? Surely it would be simpler - and less fragile - to write:

```
time_diff_components = Time.diff(@art.datetime_of_update, Time.now)
```

I don't know why `Time.diff` isn't working for you (I'm not a Ruby dev), but if the aim is to check whether the article was updated "less than 3 hours ago" then there's a simpler approach: subtract three hours from the current time, and compare the article's update time with that limit:

```
limit_time = Time.now + 3.hours
if @art.PRICEM.to_f >= eprice.to_f || @art.PRICEM.blank? && @art.datetime_of_update >= limit_time
```

Comment: Maybe `limit_time = Time.now + 3.hours` since OP is using Rails and therefore `ActiveSupport` anyway.

Comment: @Michael: thanks, edited. This is why it's dangerous for me to answer Ruby questions. I assume the rest of my answer is sensible though?

Comment: @JonSkeet Don't worry, the rest looks fine. Also your approach wasn't wrong, just not exactly the most idiomatic Rails code. :-)

Comment: @brabertaser1992: Well if you want articles updated within the last 3 hours, then yes...

Comment: `undefined method 'diff' for Time:Class`

Comment: @ajkochanowicz: That was in the OP's code; I suspect they ended up using the code at the end of my answer instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet Big salute to you, Sir, there is no language born on which you can't answer. You are the father of programming language.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have to be precise, you can use Rails' `time_ago_in_words` helper.

```
time_ago_in_words(Time.now - 3.hours)
#=> about 3 hours
```

of course, depending on the time difference, this can return 'minutes', 'days', etc. as well.