# How to check time left until a specific date?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I check how many days left until a specific date?

For example, I want to start executing some logic after 3 days from today? I will be hard coding today's date, and subtract now from it, but how?

**EDIT**

What I want to do is to disable devise confirmation email at model for the next three days,

```
if Rails.env== 'production' && (three days left sense 1/7/2013)
   devise :confirmable
end
```

Comment: Can you please explain yourself better ? I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: No, I mean is the code going to continue to run for three days or will the program be restarted at some point/

Comment: After the three days, it will run for ever ..

Comment: So does the program run the entire time ? or only supposed to be started 3 days from now ?

Comment: If you're going to hardcode a date then hardcode the date you want to use and not today. Then just compare Date.today with your date Date(2013,1,10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why bother?

```
if Rails.env== 'production' && Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i >= 20130110
    devise :confirmable 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [time_diff](https://rubygems.org/gems/time_diff) gem to get the difference in terms of year, month, week, day, hour, minute and second that can be easily achieved as I did so.

Check this - 
 [Rails calculate time difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338721/rails-calculate-time-difference?rq=1)

You will get your answer there.

Comment: is it that hard to use a gem? I expect the code to be one line or two, right?

Answer (score 0):

If im getting it right ,

you just store the start time in a variable 
then check it against the current time (you'll get the diff in seconds ) 
and if its larger then 72(3 days) the `if` statement will be done.

```
require 'time'
start_time=Time.now

if Rails.env== 'production' && ( (Time.new - start_time)/3600 >72 )
   devise :confirmable
end
```

Comment: nice, but, I need to hard code the start_time, otherwise time difference will be always zero

Comment: your program ends and you want it to start again after 3 days on its own?

Comment: its not a program, its a website

Answer (score 0):

in your class first you have to set date
e.g:

in your case you need to do something like this:

```
  ("object name".date.to_time<=time.now+3)
   (do something)if x.date.to_time<=today
```

the technique to_time make`s you able to choose time (day,weeks,month,year)

```
ENV.all.each do|env|
  where (env.date.to_time<= Time.now+3)
   if Rails.env== 'production' && (env.date.to_time== today)
      devise :confirmable
   end
```

Comment: x.date ? can you please fill a real date example?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if Time.now >= <your_time_object> + 3.days
  # start executing some logic
end
```